# For 2.4GHz/5GHz wifi which is best for Apple devices: different SSIDs or same?

Tags: network, wifi

My WiFi router, a Netgear Nighthawk, can do 2.4GHz and 5GHz; and it can have the same SSID or different for those ranges.

We run MacBooks, an iPad, an iPad Nano and an iPhone 4 on the network. Does it make sense to have both ranges on one SSID and let the devices pick the right frequency or keep them separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar set up (not same router).

While using the same SSID, I noticed instability, probably due to randomness  of who gets what.

So now I have separate SSID for 2.4 and 5 GHz and I decide who connects to what.

Answer (score 0):

Either way, the devices will not necessarily pick the strongest signal, they tend to hang onto the one they're on til they lose it completely.

At least with separate SSIDs you can look at which it's attached to currently & force it over if necessary.
Requires 2 sign-ins initially, but after that it will either look after itself, or you can manually check & swap over.